# Is there any ways to copy images to the clipboard when clicking on custom button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy an image to the clipboard and use it in my webpage. But I couldn't store the image data in the clipboard. I tried executing copy commands but I could only able to copy text.  Kindly Help.

```
    function copyThings(event){
            var msgelem = event.target.previousElementSibling;
            // msgelem = the element of current button
            var msgcopied = theMsg(msgelem); // returns the content of text if text and url of the image if image.
            var copydiv = '<div contenteditable=true id="copyhidden" style="display:block;">'+msgcopied+'</div>';
            msgdiv.find('#txtarea').after(copydiv);
            msgdiv.find("#copyhidden").select();
            document.addEventListener(event, function(){
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.datatransfer.setData('URL',msgcopied); //No I18N
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            document.execCommand('copy');//No I18N
            msgdiv.find("#copyhidden").remove();

        }
```

I just wanted when I click on a particular button the image gets stored in the DataTranferItem.(i.e) the `event.clipboardData.items` must contain `{kind : file, type: image/png}`

> If I can't do that, what can be the alternate solution?

Thanks in Advance!